# What is the correct way to type-cast a number?

Tags: c, casting

Is the following program well defined or can it cause undefined behavior?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x, y;
    int i;

    assert(sizeof (x) == sizeof (i));
    x = 3.14;
    i = *(int *) &x;
    y = *(float *) &i;
    printf("%f %f\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

If it can cause undefined behavior, is there another way to change the type of a floating point value to an integer type without changing the bit pattern of the value?

Edit:

What I'm trying to implement is a macro similar to

```
#define CONV(T, n) ((T) (n))
```

but which doesn't alter the bit pattern of n.

Comment: Use `memcpy()`?

Comment: You are doing type punning. On that see [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's undefined behavior to access `float` data through an `int*` pointer (it violates strict aliasing).

The standard way to do type punning is to write `memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof(i))` instead of `i = *(int*)&x`.

This is a good resource: [What is Strict Aliasing and Why Do We Care](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8)

Comment: Also worth noting is that this won't actually result in a memcpy call. The compiler will emit appropriate machine code for the target CPU that looks like *as if* `i = *(int*)&x` was used and was well defined.

Comment: Thanks for the information. What I'm trying to implement is a type casting expression or function. What is the best option in this case, should I define a function which memcpy the input parameter to a local variable and returns it? Or is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: What you're trying to do is *not type-casting*. It's type-punning, or reinterpretation of the representation of one type as a representation of a different type. Type-casting is a (forced, via a cast operator) conversion of *values* that has nothing to do with *representations*.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE OK, I have edited the question now.